# How to Handle User Permissions in a Next.js UI with OIDC-Client

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, openiddict

I'm working on a project that involves implementing an authentication server using OAuth2 with PKCE. The authentication server, in this case, is Microsoft Identity Server with OpenIddict. Upon user login, the server provides both ID tokens and access tokens, with user permissions included as claims in the access token.

The reason I need to obtain these permissions from the access token in my UI, which is built using Next.js and utilizes the oidc-client library, is that I need to conditionally enable or disable certain features based on the user's permissions.

Here are the steps I've already taken:

Implemented OAuth2 with PKCE for user authentication using Microsoft Identity Server and OpenIddict.

Configured the authentication server to include user permissions as claims in the access token.

But I got to know inspecting the access token directly in the UI is not a good thing to do and opeiddict encrypts the access token payload so I can't access it in the UI (in default openiddict encrypt the access token but can disable it)

according oauth 2.0, what is the best way to access the permissions from the UI

Answer (score 1):

Access tokens are designed to be read by APIs. So to get access token data a UI must call its API. Here is an [example view model of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/views/userInfo/userInfoViewModel.ts#L84) which gets some user attributes from the OAuth user info endpoint and sone other user attributes from its own API.